# Error Index fuera de rango en python

Tags: python

espero alguien me pueda dar una luz con la signación de un valor dependiendo de una tupla, quiero asignar la posicion 3 a mi variable, pero al momento de hacerlo me indica que esta fuera de rango, mi tupla sale de una consulta en una base de datos, la cual me trae 4 datos, de estos cuatro necesito el ultimo que seria el 3, contando el 0.

He intentado asignar el resultado de esta consulta en un arreglo con el animo de ver si es por esto, sin embargo me sigue presentando el mismo problema.

Este es el log de ejecución:

```
Ad117
[('220008322401', '987654321', 'SOLICITANTE', 547)] #Este es el resultado de mi consulta

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/adherencia_revision.py", line 1340, in <module>
    Ejecutar()
  File "D:/adherencia_revision.py", line 1309, in Ejecutar
    Ad117()
  File "D:/adherencia_revision.py", line 1038, in Ad117
    print("bgAnterior[3] ",bgAnterior[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Este es mi código:

```
try:
    with open("D:/consulta.sql","r") as query:
        sql = query.read()
        with BDMicro() as consulta:
            gAnterior = consulta.query(sql)
except Exception as err:
    print(err)

bgAnterior = []
for row in gAnterior:
    bgAnterior.append(row)
print(bgAnterior)

if gAnterior:       
    print("bgAnterior[3] ",bgAnterior[3])
    anterior = bgAnterior[3]
    print("anterior ",anterior)
    
    if anterior in fondob:
        if actual in fondoa:
            res1 = (rowAd[0],rowAd[1],observ,accion)
            res.append(res1)
```

Comment: `bgAnterior` es una lista de `rows`. La expresión `bgAnterior[3]` se refiere al cuarto elemento de la lista, pero la lista sólo tiene uno. Probablemente sea `btAnterior[0][3]` lo que buscas: primer elemento de la lista, cuarto de la tupla.}

Comment: Ahí sólo tienes un elemento en esa lista, una tupla, con 4 elementos. `bgAnterior[0][3]` llega al valor que buscas

Comment: hice la prueba de imprimir cada una de las posiciones desde la cero de esta manera:
print("bgAnterior[0] ",bgAnterior[0])
En pantallama me muetsra esto:
bgAnterior[0]  ('220008322401', '33015161813', 'SOLICITANTE F. PERSONAL', 547)

Comment: Pues ya te lo han dicho: la lista contiene sólo un elemento. El elemento es una 4-tupla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo con la pregunta, el resultado de la consulta queda en `bgAnterior`

```
bgAnterior = [('220008322401', '987654321', 'SOLICITANTE', 547)]
```

Esta es una lista y contiene un sólo elemento, que es una 4-tupla.

Para recuperar la tupla es cosa de extraer el primer elemento:

```
info = bgAnterior[0] # info = ('220008322401', '987654321', 'SOLICITANTE', 547)
```

y de la tupla puedes sacar el campo que desees usando indices otra vez:

```
info[3] -> 547
```

No es necesario extraer la tupla para acceder al elemento; puedes combinar ambos accesos en uno asolo

```
bgAnterior[0][3] -> 547
```

**Demo**

```
bgAnterior = [('220008322401', '987654321', 'SOLICITANTE', 547)]
print("bgAnterior[0][3] ", bgAnterior[0][3])
```

produce

```
bgAnterior[0][3]  547

Process finished with exit code 0
```